# How to parse command line arguments with SWITCH in BATCH file

Tags: batch-file, switch-statement

We are trying to make a switch statement which is parsing command line argument in a batch file.

```
mybatch.bat -a 10 -b name -c India --zipcode 20
```

Only `-a`, `-b`, `-c` are parsing parameter (which is starts with `-`).

Our code will be like:

```
for %%x in (%*) do (
     switch(%%x) (
          case a:
                 SET first_number=%arg%
                 break
          case b:
                 SET name=%arg%
          case c:
                 for %%x in (%*) do (
                       SET place =%place% %arg%
                  )
          default:
                  echo wrong parameter
           )
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally you try to keep things simple and have a set order for the parameters. To handle parameters in any, random order is a lot more effort than just knowing that %1 = number, %2 = name and %3 onwards = place.

That said, here's an attempt at a solution. I'm ignoring --params in the place section, just joining the values together.

```
@echo off
setlocal

:loop
if x%1 equ x goto done
set param=%1
if %param:~0,1% equ - goto checkParam
:paramError
echo Parameter error: %1 

:next
shift /1
goto loop

:checkParam
if "%1" equ "-a" goto A
if "%1" equ "-b" goto B
if "%1" equ "-c" goto C
goto paramError

:A
    shift /1
    set first_number=%1
    goto next

:B
    shift /1
    set name=%1
    goto next

:C
    set place=
:GetPlaces
    shift /1
    set param=%1
    if not defined param goto donePlaces
    if %param:~0,2% equ -- (
        shift /1
        goto processPlace
    )
    if %param:~0,1% equ - goto donePlaces
:processPlace
echo.%place%
    if x%1 neq x (
        set place=%place% %1
        goto GetPlaces
    )
:donePlaces
    rem remove leading space
    if defined place set place=%place:~1%
    goto loop



:done

echo num=%first_number%     name=%name%     place=%place%
```

Comment: When I run this with the example arguments given: `-a 10 -b name -c India --zipcode 20` I get the output: `India` and then this error `2 was unexpected at this time.`

Comment: Good find @SamHasler, I've updated my example to add `if not defined param goto donePlaces`. Clearly all my tests were with -c as an earlier param

Answer (score 14):

The Batch file below parses all arguments that start with `-` and creates a series of variables that start with "option" and the names and values of all options given:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "option="
for %%a in (%*) do (
   if not defined option (
      set arg=%%a
      if "!arg:~0,1!" equ "-" set "option=!arg!"
   ) else (
      set "option!option!=%%a"
      set "option="
   )
)

SET option
```

For example:

```
>test -a 10 -b name -c India --zipcode 20
option--zipcode=20
option-a=10
option-b=name
option-c=India
```

This way, you need to make no changes in the parsing code if you want to add/change/delete any option, just use the value of the option you want. For example:

```
if defined option-x (
   echo Option -x given: "%option-x%"
) else (
   echo Option -x not given
)
```

Answer (score 1):

there's no switch command in batch.You need to workaround this with if statements:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /l %%a in (1,2,6) do (
    set /a next=%%a+1

    set param=%%a

    call set _param=%%!param!
    call set _next=%%!next!

    rem echo -!next! -!_next! #!_param! #%%a 

    if "!_param!" equ "-a" (
        set first_number=!_next!
    )

    if "!_param!" equ "-b" (
        call set name=!_next!
    )

    if "!_param!" equ "-c" (
        set place=!_next!
    )

)

for %%a in (place first_number name) do (
    if not defined %%a set wrong_parameter=1
)

if defined wrong_parameter (
    echo wrong parameter
)

echo %place% %first_number% %name%
```

Comment: dont consider place as last argument,  -c could be second argument. <br/>
like:-<br/>

mybatch.bat -a 10 -c India --zipcode 20 -b name