# Splitting a string with double dash as delimiter containing both single & double dash in windows batch

Tags: regex, batch-file, cmd

This is the piece of code i am working on.

```
set "comd=aws iam create-group --group-name xxx --user-name yyy"
    for /f "tokens=2,3delims=--" %%a in ("%comd%") do (
       echo %%a 
       echo %%b 
    )
```

i want to take out `group-name xxx` as one token and `user-name yyy` as another, but
when i use `--` as delimiter it considers string with `-` also fit to be tokenized so in this case `group` of `create-group` is also being considered as separate token.

i want to make this code work for all the occurrences `--key value`.

Comment: The simplest thing you can do is replace -- with something really unlikely like ~. e.g. `set comd=%comd:--=~%` before your for line.

Comment: @ScottC you should really make that an answer

Comment: that's not up to me so cant do anything about it @ScottC

Comment: @SubhamTripathi see my answer, I'm suggesting you parse the string differently, not alter the way it's coming in originally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest thing you can do is replace -- with something really unlikely like ~. e.g. set comd=%comd:--=~% before your for line.

Your full block would then be:

```
set "comd=aws iam create-group --group-name xxx --user-name yyy"
set comd=%comd:--=~%
for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=~" %%a in ("%comd%") do (
   echo %%a 
   echo %%b 
)
```

You might also like to have a read of [How to parse command line arguments with SWITCH in BATCH file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28103532/how-to-parse-command-line-arguments-with-switch-in-batch-file/28105853#28105853) - a few good ideas there

Comment: Yes - the DELIMS option specifies a list of characters to be used as delimiters - ***not*** a string to be used as a delimiter.