# Storing infinite tokens in an array using windows batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

i wish to split this string in to tokens that will of the form

```
aws iam create-group -key1 value1 -key2 value2 ..... -keyn valuen
```

Tokens

```
key1 value1
key2 value2
..
keyn valuen
```

i will always need value after token 1 i.e leaving this `aws iam create-group` for that i wrote this script

```
for /f "tokens=2*delims=-" %%p in ("%comd%") do (
        // THIS IS SUPPOSSED TO FIND ALL THE TOKENS AND INSERT IT INTO THE ARRAY        
)
```

how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

set "command=aws iam create-group -key1 value1 -key2 value2 -key3 valuen"

call :map_pars %command%

set -

goto :eof

:map_pars

shift 
shift
shift


:repeat

if "%~1" neq "" if "%~2" neq "" (
    set "%~1=%~2"
    shift 
    shift
    goto :repeat
) 
exit /b 0
```

Assuming that every key argument starts with `-` and the commands that not contain key-value pairs are the first three.

Answer (score 0):

As I posted in my other answer to your earlier question [Splitting a string with double dash as delimiter containing both single & double dash in windows batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29908820/splitting-a-string-with-double-dash-as-delimiter-containing-both-single-double/29909343#29909343). You might also like to have a read of [How to parse command line arguments with SWITCH in BATCH file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28103532/how-to-parse-command-line-arguments-with-switch-in-batch-file/28105853#28105853) - a few good ideas there

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "comd=aws iam create-group -key1 value1 -key2 value2 -key3 valuen"

for /F "tokens=3*" %%p in ("%comd%") do set "tokens=%%q"
set n=0
set "key="
for %%a in (%tokens:-=%) do (
   if not defined key (
      set key=%%a
   ) else (
      set /A n+=1
      set "token[!n!]=!key! %%a"
      set "key="
   )
)

rem Show the elements of "token" array:
for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do echo !token[%%i]!
```