# CMD Create Custom Commands with more than one option

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I created a custom CMD Command with a Batch Script but I dont know how to make more than 1 Option...

What I have now is a Command which looks like this:

```
yce -update
```

But I want to make a Command where you can specify what is Updated which works like this:

```
yce -update (all, appname, eb)
```

This is the entire code:

```
@echo off
SET "parameter=%~1"
if /i "%parameter%" equ "" goto :yce_help

for %%p in (help h update fiddler ) do (
  if  /i "%parameter:~1%" equ "%%~p" goto :%%~p
  rem if  /i "%parameter%" equ "%%~p" goto :%%~p
)
goto :wrong_parameter

:wrong_parameter
  echo yce: option -%parameter:~1%: is unknown
  echo yce: try 'yce -help' for more information
goto :eof

:yce_help
  echo yce: try 'yce -help' for more information
goto :eof

:h
goto :help

:help
  echo.
  echo. 
  echo.
  echo Usage: yce [options...]
  echo -update,     Updates yCE
goto :eof

:update
  echo [94mCreating Folders...[0m
  md "%userprofile%\.yce"
  md "%userprofile%\.yce\update"
  echo [94mDownloading Latest Update...[0m
  echo THIS SCRIPT DOWNLOADS THE UPDATE
  echo [94mStarting Update...[0m
  start %userprofile%\.yce\update\yce_update.bat
goto :eof
```

Comment: Duplicate: [How to parse command line arguments with SWITCH in BATCH file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28103532/how-to-parse-command-line-arguments-with-switch-in-batch-file)

Comment: Your code appears to be using VT100 type commands, but does not define an escape character for use, and does not make any attempt to determine whether the end users Operating System is capable of using such commands, or, if it is, whether such a thing is enabled for use.

Comment: You use `%~1` to capture the first parameter. What's stopping you from using `%~2` for the second one?